# jscanify cv is undefined on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use the jscanify library to scan an image.

Unfortunately, I keep on getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'imread')
```

This is the code I am using:

```js
import jscanify from 'jscanify'
import { loadImage } from 'canvas'
import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';

const scanner = new jscanify();

loadImage('test/test.png').then((testImage) => {
  const result = scanner.extractPaper(testImage, 386, 500);
  writeFileSync('test/output/result.png', result.toBuffer('image/jpeg'));
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please post the **full** error message/stack trace and not just a line of it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.